# Nginx 1.15.8 need load 1k+ ssl cert

Tags: nginx, ssl

```
erro ->  nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/$sslwww/fullchain.pem")
```

the configuration with map or with if are not working what I can do for them to work?

do not just find the path to the file

```
     map $http_host $sslwww {
        default "test.com";
        ~^(?<subdomain>([\w-]+\.)*)?(?<domain>.+)$ $domain;
        }

            server {
                        listen 80;
                        listen [::]:80;
                        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        server {
                    listen       443 ssl http2;
                    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
                    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>([\w-]+\.)*)?(?<domain>.+)$;
                    #set $sslwww "test.com"; -> not work
                    #if ($domain != "test.com"){
                    #set $sslwww $domain;
                    #}
                    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$sslwww/fullchain.pem";
        }
```

Where am I going wrong?

in use include conf but I think it would not be good. what another solution to load 1k ssl cert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable for an `ssl_certificate` as you could for the server name or many other things. That's because the certificate must be loaded with the configuration and cannot vary dynamically with each request, as other variables can.

To fix the problem you will need to obtain new TLS certificates with multiple names or wildcards.

Comment: the problem and that the system can receive the request name.domain.dot or private.dot how to run all ssl? Loading 1k + ssl would not affect performance? https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module could not be the solution?

Comment: ok, certbot certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --webroot --agree-tos --no-eff-email --email dot@gmail.com -w /usr/local/nginx/html -d name.domain.dot -d domain.dot -d other.dot -d -d -d? would be the solution?

Comment: That's pretty much the way I do it. Keep in mind that Let's Encrypt limits you to 100 names per certificate.

Comment: but then how do you get to 1k?

Comment: @FelipeKusk Use wildcard certs or different `server` blocks.

Comment: will not using about 1000 server block affect performance?

Comment: @FelipeKusk If you have 1000 names, then you only need 10 certs, and 10 `server` blocks, because you can have 100 names in each certificate.